# Is there a way in ADF DataFlow expresion builder to use variables instead of values?

Tags: azure-data-factory

This is the condition in a Select transformation:

```
type=='double'&&position>0&&position<=12
```

[image]

can i somehow store the values in a variable...var1=0 and var2=12,then use it like this:

```
type=='double'&&position>var1&&position<=var2
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two parameters in Data Flow. And then use this expression:
`type=='double'&&position>$var1&&position<=$var2`.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that before,it does not work...it returns "no input columns matched"

Comment: @ToniVukasinovic If you hardcode those values, it can work?

Comment: @ToniVukasinovic I tried this and that expression can work. Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: i have edited my question so you can see the screenshots

Comment: @ToniVukasinovic When I click the `Preview the results of this mapping` button, I get the same result  "no input columns matched". You can try to click the `Data preview` button, it shows all the mapping column on my side.